# How to re-order a list of tuples according to the order of the elements in another list

Tags: python-3.x

There are two lists:

```
list1 = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
list2 = ['C', 'A', 'B']
```

How can I reorganize the tuples in `list1` so that the first elements of all the tuples are in the same order as those in `list2`?

i.e., the expected result is

```
list1 = [('C', 3), ('A', 1), ('B', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension as follows:

```
d = dict(list1)
[(i,d.get(i)) for i in list2]
 [('C', 3), ('A', 1), ('B', 2)]
```

Comment: this is incredibly inefficient: `i,dict(list1).get(i)`  why re-create the `dict` on every iteration of a loop? Just create the dictionary outside.